# Backbone: mixins with conflicting methods

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I started to use mixins from this post: [Proper way of doing view mixins in Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7853731/240993)

```
var MyMixin = {
  foo: "bar",
  sayFoo: function(){alert(this.foo);}
}

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
 // ...
});

_.extend(MyView.prototype, MyMixin);

myView = new MyView();
myView.sayFoo(); //=> "bar"
```

Which works fine unless its a conflicting method in the mixing: Example `render()` in mixin and `render()` in the actual view.

How can I go about firing the mixin methods first then the actual view methods?

Comment: You want both the original render as well as the mixed in render to fire? You'll need to do more than extend for that to happen.

Comment: A mixin that defines a `render` method? That's sort of rude, isn't it?

Comment: at this point I have a considerable amount, similar views that have most the same code inside of the render method, need to boilerplate it some.

Answer (score 2):

I might recommend using [Backbone.Cocktail](https://github.com/onsi/cocktail) which provides a really succinct way of specifying mixins (that respect inheritance):

```
var Mixin = {
  initialize: function() {
    console.log("I'll be called as well as the class's constructor!");
  }
};

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  mixins: [ MyMixin ]
});
```

I've detailed it in this [blog post](http://www.salsify.com/blog/using-cocktail-to-create-mixins-for-backbone-models-that-respect-inheritance/1283).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use the other answer provided on that question: [Backbone-Mixin Gist](https://gist.github.com/3652964)?