# How to reuse render function for multiple views in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

I'm working on an app in Backbone, and I have multiple views that have the same render function:

```
render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

How do I reuse this function in multiple views so I can follow the old DRY way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mixin pattern specified here: [Proper way of doing view mixins in Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853731/proper-way-of-doing-view-mixins-in-backbone)

```
var renderable = {
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
};

var view = Backbone.View.extend({
//other methods
});

_.extend(view.prototype, renderable);

var myView = new view();
myView.render();
```

Comment: Now that I know they're called mixins, I'm seeing a lot more info on them. It also appears that you can skip the _.extend(...) but including `mixin: [renderable, ...]` when you define the view.

Answer (score 0):

Extend another view

```
var BeefedupView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var myView = BeefedupView.extend({
    // Do super cool stuff here...
});
```