# Backbone Marionette, set global BeforeRender in all views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, frameworks, marionette

I'm trying to add a language support in my website and I need to add this code so it will run before marionette render in all the views no matter which type.

```
onBeforeRender: function(){

    var helpers = this.templateHelpers();
    this.templateHelpers = function(){
        return $.extend( (helpers), {
            lang : function () {
                return function(val, render) {
                    return lang(val);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't want to extend all the views and put this code in each of them,
I wonder if there is a way to just put this code in some place and it will run before every render

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to extend the prototype with something like

```
_.extend(Marionette.View.prototype, {

    onBeforeRender: function(){

        var helpers = this.templateHelpers();
        this.templateHelpers = function(){
            return $.extend( (helpers), {
                lang : function () {
                    return function(val, render) {
                        return lang(val);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

})
```

Naturally, that means that if one of your marionette views defines its own `onBeforeRender`, you'll need to call the implementation on the `View` prototype "by hand".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a view [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853731/proper-way-of-doing-view-mixins-in-backbone) with your code and extend every view with this mixin

```
var LangMixin = { 
    onBeforeRender: function(){
        var helpers = this.templateHelpers();
            this.templateHelpers = function(){
                return $.extend( (helpers), {
                    lang : function () {
                    return function(val, render) {          
                        return lang(val);
                        }                                                                       
                    }   
                }); 
           }            
    }
}   

var YourView= Backbone.View.extend({
     // ...
});

_.extend(YourView.prototype, LangMixin);
```